# Weird I/O stalls affecting a whole desktop

Tags: io, delay

After a recent hardware migration I started experiencing weird I/O stalls affecting my desktop Debian Stretch system. Typical symptoms, all happening during each stall:

- I stop being able to interact with Chromium, my web browser. Nothing works: webpage scrolling (usually this is the way I notice the stall), switching tabs, etc. No mouse-over actions either, whether on a web page or Chromium UI.
- In a virtual terminal, I can't run new processes anymore. For example, I open a new tab in `mate-terminal` and my shell doesn't show up, just the cursor blinking. In a terminal with shell opened before a stall, I can type a command, but usually it doesn't start; `sudo something` doesn't even ask for a password.
- Other programs, like RStudio, can't save anything to disk and often hang when they attempt to.
- I see in the logs of `journald -f` that if the stall is long enough, `journald` itself restarts, example:

  ```
    sty 30 14:03:54 liori-pc systemd[1]: systemd-journald.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=6/ABRT
    sty 30 14:03:54 liori-pc systemd[1]: systemd-journald.service: Unit entered failed state.
    sty 30 14:03:54 liori-pc systemd[1]: systemd-journald.service: Failed with result 'watchdog'.
    sty 30 14:03:54 liori-pc systemd[1]: systemd-journald.service: Service has no hold-off time, scheduling restart.
    sty 30 14:03:54 liori-pc systemd[1]: Stopped Flush Journal to Persistent Storage.
    sty 30 14:03:54 liori-pc systemd[1]: Stopping Flush Journal to Persistent Storage...
    sty 30 14:03:54 liori-pc systemd[1]: Stopped Journal Service.
    sty 30 14:03:54 liori-pc systemd[1]: Starting Journal Service...
    sty 30 14:03:54 liori-pc systemd-journald[23935]: Journal started
    sty 30 14:03:54 liori-pc systemd-journald[23935]: System journal (/var/log/journal/2318080f60e357aaf765e98d0000035c) is 2.1G, max 4.0G, 1.8G free.
  ```
- When using dm_crypt, a `dmcrypt_write` process starts taking 100% of a single CPU core (I later got rid of dm_crypt from this system, but stalls still happen).
- I observe `/proc/meminfo` and see that the `Dirty` number is never more than few megabytes. Notably, during a stall, this number doesn't change.
- In rare cases, I even get a kernel message in the form of "INFO: task «some process» blocked for more than 120 seconds.", with «some_process» being usually mdX_raid5, chromium or one of its threads, etc. [Example log](https://gist.github.com/liori/1201305ceb5787308c46b051aa16fbe3).

Initially my setup was just a single 600GB ext4 file system on a partition on a single 1TB drive (current `/dev/sdd`). Then I migrated to 3×6TB drives (`/dev/sd{b,c,e}`), with LVM-based raid5, bcache with its cache on an SSD drive, then dm_crypt — and that's when the stalls started. In the process of debugging, I simplified it to just LVM-raid5, with no bcache or dm_crypt; stalls still happen, though I feel they are less often now.

This kind of stall happens several times a day and usually lasts few minutes. I noticed that I can break it by explicitly requesting some disk operation: I was able to sometimes break it by logging in to this system by ssh from a remote machine, or (almost always) by just `cat /dev/sdb >/dev/null` or `cat /dev/sdc >/dev/null` (sometimes one, sometimes the other works; notably `cat /dev/sde >/dev/null` never helped). Then, everything that stalled suddenly start working again.

So I suspect the problem is caused by one of or interaction of:

- The drives: all three are Seagate Skyhawk ST6000VX0023. Two of them unused before this setup, the third one used for half a year (`/dev/sdc`).
- Disk controllers: the motherboard: [`Gigabyte Z68X-UD3H-B3`](https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/GA-Z68X-UD3H-B3-rev-10#sp) has two controllers: `Marvell 88SE9172` where one of the drives is connected to, and the chipset-builtin controller (`Intel® Z68`) with two others (can I check which one is where in software?).
- Some bug in the controller kernel drivers.
- Some bug in LVM or raid5.

This is a Debian Stretch system with some backported packages installed, most notably kernel `4.19.0-0.bpo.1-amd64`. Intel Core i7-2600k, 16GB of RAM.

At this point I ran out of ideas. How do I debug this problem further?

Edit: I started a script that's reading a single random sector from one of these drives every 4 seconds, and had no stalls for 2 days now. So indeed it does look like some system component (LVM? raid?) doesn't properly wake up devices from some kind of a low-power mode when it's necessary.

Edit: I no longer have access to this system, so I can no longer test any hypothesis. I can only say that after running that script I was no longer getting the stalls. I wish I knew how to debug it, though.

Comment: Does an actual time gap show up in the journalctl output? I note that there doesn't appear to be in the output you've quoted above - but that happens to start about where my journalctl output seemed to generally resume after a pause like this on my former laptop. (You're not likely to have the problem that laptop had, however - it had been bought brand new in May 2008, and was a low power laptop so only 32 bit.)

Comment: @EdGrimm, I think so. At least, when I notice the stall and switch to `journalctl -f` output running in some terminal, I don't get any new messages until the stall ends. That doesn't mean I know when exactly the stall started.

Comment: I expected from your description of the stall that journalctl -f wouldn't report anything until the stall ended. But when the stall ends, it could just log new stuff (unlikely, unless journalctl itself was restarted at the end), it could catch up part of the way, or it could catch up all of the way, such that there's no noticeable gap. It would be much easier to tell on a busier machine that had regularly occurring logging. It's not really something I expect you'd be able to answer off-hand, because our brains try to only note things that are noteworthy.

Comment: The no more logs at all to cover the time of the gap could also happen if your problem is CPU-related, such that your CPU is zoning out for a period of time. I *haven't* actually seen that behavior since journald and systemd, but I am recalling a friend's computer that would overheat and pause for a minute or two until the system cooled down back around 2002. But if it's a drive issue, the logging would probably catch up after the pause finished. I'm not ruling out non-CPU non-drive issues. I'm just mulling the options, because while I'm trying to be helpful, hardware support isn't my area.

Comment: I have had similar, but not identical issues for quite some time now. Dropping caches `echo 3 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` helps, at least for some time. I don't know the real reason for this, and I'd be very interested in finding out.

Comment: @EdGrimm: I'm starting to suspect that the stalls happen only when the machine is actually not busy. I didn't get any stall yesterday when I was running a heavy I/O task for ~10 hours, and normally I would get a few of them. To test this hypothesis, I'm now leaving a small process doing small random reads all over the drives. The machine is certainly not overheating: I managed to observe sensors twice before, and except for the case of dm_crypt taking 100% of a CPU core, the temperatures of both the CPU and drives did not go over ~55°C.

Comment: That sounds like the stalls are due to the drives going into a low-power mode and taking a really long time to come out of it. My knowledge of how to fix that issue went obsolete with IDE, but hopefully that suggestion will help you find a better answer, or somebody with a better answer will come by and give it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seagate Skyhawk models have a "Standby to ready" time that's 23-30 seconds long, on the 6TB model.  The 1TB model had that number at 6ms; the stall went up considerably during the transition to 2TB.  I suspect your drive is switching to idle where it only buffers I/O, then stalling when you try to write to it, as it spins up.

The drives support 4 power management modes:  Active, Idle, Standby, and Sleep.  The relevant section from the manual [says](https://www.seagate.com/files/www-content/product-content/skyhawk/en-us/docs/100804836n.pdf):

> "Each  time  the  drive  performs  an  Active  function  (read,  write
> or  seek),  the  standby  timer  is  reinitialized  and  begins
> counting down  from  its  specified  delay  times  to  zero.  If  the
> standby  timer  reaches  zero  before  any  drive  activity  is
> required,  the  drive makes  a  transition  to  Standby  mode.  In
> both  Idle  and  Standby  mode,  the  drive  accepts  all  commands
> and  returns  to  Active mode when disk access is necessary."

Changing the power management mode from within Linux to eliminate Standby mode is a pain.  Drive vendors provide utilities for this sort of thing, but usually they require booting their ISO or using a Windows only utility.  I've had some success with tweaking the standby timeout using hdparm; here's a [starter tutorial](https://michlstechblog.info/blog/linux-switch-a-idle-hard-disk-into-standby-mode/).

Comment: Oh, that's hideous. So it's essentially an equivalent to WD idle timer? Going to accept your answer, as it matches the observations I had at the time.